# How can I assign a value to a color slider from three menu items in an option menu?

Tags: python, maya

I am doing a rigging tool and I want to assign a different color to the controllers for right and left using a slider. the idea is to select en item from the menu and get the color for that. but for now it is working just the first item and none the others.

My code is inside a class, at this point I have the window, the function to select a joint and a function to change the color. I am querying the selection for the option menu. This information is use by the three conditionals to set a color for each menu item. However, it works just the first option and none the other two. I tried to do the same code but without a class just defining the function and it works. What can I be doing wrong inside the class? I am kind of new in python and this is my first time doing a tool for ringing.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.mel as mel
import sys
import math


class rigCreator:

    def __init__(self, *args):

       #self.startFunction()
        self.window = "uiWindow"
        self.title = "Rigging Tool Bipeds"
        self.winSize = (150, 200)
        self.createUI()



    def createUI(self, *args):
        #check if window and prefs exist. If yes, delete


        if cmds.window(self.window, ex=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, wnd=True)
        elif cmds.windowPref(self.window, ex=True):
            cmds.windowPref(self.window, r=True)

        self.window = cmds.window(self.window, t=self.title, wh = self.winSize, s=1, mnb=1, mxb=1)
        self.mainForm = cmds.formLayout(nd=100)
        self.tagLine= cmds.text(label = "Rig Tool")
        cmds.frameLayout(label="1. Choose the root joint")
        self.Layout = cmds.columnLayout(adj=1)

        #Add a saparator to the window
        cmds.separator()

        # button to select the first joint 
        cmds.rowColumnLayout (nc = 2, cs=[(1,6), (2,6)])
        rootBt = cmds.textField ('rootJnt', tx = 'First joint of your Arm chain', w = 250)
        #cmds.textFieldButtonGrp('rootJnt', width=380, cal=(8, "center"), cw3=(100, 200, 75), h=40, pht="First joint of your Arm chain", l="First Joint", bl="Select", bc = lambda x: findJnt(), p=self.Layout)
        cmds.button(l = 'Select', c = lambda x:self.findJnt())

        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame = cmds.frameLayout("2. Name options", lv=1, li=1, w=250)

        #cmds.text(label="", align = "left")
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=4, cs=[(1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6)])
        #cmds.text('Side', l='Side:')
        cmds.optionMenu('Part_Side', l='Side:', cc=lambda x:self.colorChange(), acc=1, ni=1)
        cmds.menuItem(label='L_')
        cmds.menuItem(label='R_')
        cmds.menuItem(label='_')
        cmds.text('Part', l='Part:')
        cmds.optionMenu('part_Body')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Arm')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Leg')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Spine')


        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame2 = cmds.frameLayout("3. Type of rig", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=3, cs=[(1,6), (2,6), (3,6)])
        cmds.radioCollection("limb side")
        cmds.radioButton(label='IK/FK', select=True)
        cmds.radioButton(label='IK')
        cmds.radioButton(label='FK')


        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame3 = cmds.frameLayout("4. Thick if you want to apply stretch", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=1, cs=[(1,6)])
        cmds.checkBox( label='Stretchy limb', align='center' )

        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)


        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame4 = cmds.frameLayout("5. Pick icon color", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.gridLayout(nr=1, nc=5, cwh=[62,20])
        cmds.iconTextButton('darkBlue_Btn', bgc=[.000,.016,.373])
        cmds.iconTextButton('lightBlue_Btn', bgc=[0,0,1])
        cmds.iconTextButton('Brown_Btn', bgc=[.537,.278,.2])
        cmds.iconTextButton('red_Btn', bgc=[1,0,0])
        cmds.iconTextButton('Yellow_Btn', bgc=[1,1,0])
        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)

        colorBt = cmds.colorIndexSliderGrp('rigColor', w=250, h=50, cw2=(150,0), min=0, max=31, v=7)
        #This button will creat the chain of joins with streatch and squach
        cmds.button('b_create', label='Create', h=30, c='create()') 

        #show the window
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)


    def findJnt(self, *args):

        self.root = cmds.ls(sl=True)


        if len(self.root) == 1:

            selRoot = self.root[0]
            rootBt = cmds.textField ('rootJnt', e=1, tx=selRoot)
        else:

            cmds.warning ('Please select only the first joint!')

    def colorChange(self, *args):


        self.limbSide = cmds.optionMenu('Part_Side', q=1, sl=1)


        if self.limbSide ==1:
            self.sideColor = 7

        if self.limbSide == 2:

            self.sideColor = 14

        if self.limbSide ==3:
            self.sideColor = 18

        colorBt = cmds.colorIndexSliderGrp('rigColor', e=1, v=self.sideColor)


    def partBody(self, *args):
        pass


    def rigType(self, *args):

        pass




rigCreator()
```

Comment: it looks like the way is to .setattr:  https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/how-to-set-rgb-color-for-drawing-overrides-with-python/td-p/7592153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did just clean the lambda and comma function and it was working as expected for me.
Because you don't seem to be familiar with maya ui/class, I've cleaned your whole script with some line comments beginning with DW :
So you can find how to manage maya ui more easily !

Don't hesitate to look at partial, I've lots of posts with some tips, hope it helps :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.mel as mel
import sys
import math
from functools import partial


def create(rigType, sideColor, isStretch, *args):

    # DW : refreshed every time by property that is executing before being passed
    if rigType == 0:
        print('IK/FK mode')
    elif rigType == 1:
        print('IK mode')
    elif rigType == 2:
        print('FK mode')

    # DW : in this state of the script, it will return always 7 because there is no refresh query
    #      so you can see to pass outside your class some arguments
    #      below an example for an alternative of property
    print('color picked is {}'.format(sideColor))

    # DW : in this example the function for getting the status is passed
    #      it is different from property because we still use to execute the command
    if isStretch():
        print('rig is stretchy')
    else:
        print('no stretch')

    # Dw : note that if you create an instance of your window inside a variable :
    # ui = rigCreator()
    # ui.ikfkPick is something you can print at any moment to debug
    # any variable with 'self' would be replaced by 'ui' in this case 


class rigCreator:

    # DW : default colour, self don't need to be specify but it is like so
    #      personally I put the important parameters or parameters that set default values on top
    #      it is easier when parsing the code few month later
    sideColor = 7  #: DW : don't hesitate to do inline comment to say this is RED color (im followng google doctstring https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html)
    isStretch = 0
    ikfkPick = 0  #: pick IK/FK option,  1 for IK, 2 for FK

    def __init__(self, *args):

       #self.startFunction()
        self.window = "uiWindow"
        self.title = "Rigging Tool Bipeds"
        self.winSize = (150, 200)
        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):
        # DW : only put *args if you are using maya command flags, otherwise no need
        #check if window and prefs exist. If yes, delete


        if cmds.window(self.window, ex=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, wnd=True)
        elif cmds.windowPref(self.window, ex=True):
            cmds.windowPref(self.window, r=True)

        self.window = cmds.window(self.window, t=self.title, wh = self.winSize, s=1, mnb=1, mxb=1)
        self.mainForm = cmds.formLayout(nd=100)
        self.tagLine= cmds.text(label = "Rig Tool")
        cmds.frameLayout(label="1. Choose the root joint")
        self.Layout = cmds.columnLayout(adj=1)

        #Add a saparator to the window
        cmds.separator()

        # button to select the first joint 
        cmds.rowColumnLayout (nc = 2, cs=[(1,6), (2,6)])
        self.tf_rootBt = cmds.textField ('rootJnt', tx = 'First joint of your Arm chain', w = 250)
        #cmds.textFieldButtonGrp('rootJnt', width=380, cal=(8, "center"), cw3=(100, 200, 75), h=40, pht="First joint of your Arm chain", l="First Joint", bl="Select", bc = lambda x: findJnt(), p=self.Layout)
        # DW : use lambda only to parse arguments, the better way to not make confusion is to use partial module 
        cmds.button(l = 'Select', c = self.findJnt)

        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame = cmds.frameLayout("2. Name options", lv=1, li=1, w=250)

        #cmds.text(label="", align = "left")
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=4, cs=[(1,6), (2,6), (3,6), (4,6)])
        #cmds.text('Side', l='Side:')
        # DW : string naming can be dangerous, if another script create this type of name, it will conflict
        #      put your ctrl name into a variable or a class variable if you are using it somewhere else
        #      Same don't use lambda if you are not parsing arguments
        self.om_partside = cmds.optionMenu('Part_Side', l='Side:', cc=self.colorChange, acc=1, ni=1)
        cmds.menuItem(label='L_')
        cmds.menuItem(label='R_')
        cmds.menuItem(label='_')
        cmds.text('Part', l='Part:')
        cmds.optionMenu('part_Body')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Arm')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Leg')
        cmds.menuItem(label='Spine')


        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame2 = cmds.frameLayout("3. Type of rig", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=3, cs=[(1,6), (2,6), (3,6)])
        # DW :conforming to the default user settings on top of the class
        # demonstrate property in class
        self.rc_ikfk = cmds.radioCollection("limb side")
        for x, lb in enumerate(['IK/FK', 'IK', 'FK']):
            if x == self.ikfkPick:
                defvalue = True
            else:
                defvalue = False
            cmds.radioButton(label=lb, select=defvalue)

        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame3 = cmds.frameLayout("4. Thick if you want to apply stretch", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=1, cs=[(1,6)])
        # DW : adding default value, class variable naming
        self.ckb_stretch = cmds.checkBox( label='Stretchy limb', align='center', value=self.isStretch, cc=self.getStretch)

        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)


        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)
        frame4 = cmds.frameLayout("5. Pick icon color", lv=True, li=1, w=250)
        cmds.gridLayout(nr=1, nc=5, cwh=[62,20])
        cmds.iconTextButton('darkBlue_Btn', bgc=[.000,.016,.373])
        cmds.iconTextButton('lightBlue_Btn', bgc=[0,0,1])
        cmds.iconTextButton('Brown_Btn', bgc=[.537,.278,.2])
        cmds.iconTextButton('red_Btn', bgc=[1,0,0])
        cmds.iconTextButton('Yellow_Btn', bgc=[1,1,0])
        cmds.setParent(self.Layout)

        self.sl_colorBt = cmds.colorIndexSliderGrp('rigColor', w=250, h=50, cw2=(150,0), min=0, max=31, v= self.sideColor)
        #This button will creat the chain of joins with streatch and squach
        # DW : never use comma for executing some function, if you use this script as a module afterward, you will have problems dealing with python namespacing
        #      maya is always passing a default argument True, so put *args in any command that is used by your ui controls
        cmds.button('b_create', label='Create', h=30, c=partial(create, self.rigType, self.sideColor, self.getStretch)) 

        #show the window
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)


    def findJnt(self, *args):

        self.root = cmds.ls(sl=True, type='joint', l=True)
        # DW : just becaue I was toying around the concept of root, sorry... ignor below
        rootAbove = [i for i in self.root[0].split('|')[1:] if cmds.nodeType(i) == 'joint']
        if rootAbove[0] != self.root[0].split('|')[-1]:
            cmds.warning('you didn\'t choose the top joint !')        

        if len(self.root) == 1:
            selRoot = self.root[0]
            # DW : you dont have to store your edit, use class variable instead of string name
            cmds.textField (self.tf_rootBt, e=1, tx=selRoot.split('|')[-1])
        else:
            cmds.warning ('Please select only the first joint!')

    def colorChange(self, *args):

        # DW : you don't need to put self on limbSide has you are not using it anywhere else
        limbSide = cmds.optionMenu(self.om_partside, q=1, sl=1)
        # DW : putting some elif
        if limbSide == 1:
            self.sideColor = 7
        elif limbSide == 2:
            self.sideColor = 14
        elif limbSide ==3:
            self.sideColor = 18
        # DW : conforming editing controls
        cmds.colorIndexSliderGrp(self.sl_colorBt, e=1, v=self.sideColor)


    def partBody(self, *args):
        pass

    @property
    def rigType(self):
        '''Returns:
               int: option selected in ui'''
        # DW : demonstrating property usage and partial
        rb = cmds.radioCollection(self.rc_ikfk, q=True, select=True)
        cia = [i.split('|')[-1] for i in cmds.radioCollection(self.rc_ikfk, q=True, cia=True)]
        return cia.index(rb)


    def getStretch(self, *args):
        """function to get if the user need stretchy things

        Note:
            *args is just here to bypass maya default added True argument

        Returns:
            bool: use stretch or not

        """
        # dw making some example function with some docstring
        self.isStretch = cmds.checkBox(self.ckb_stretch, q=True, value=True)
        return self.isStretch

rigCreator()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's working. As you saw, I am kind of new with python and I have been struggling a little bit. It is really helpful how you cleaned the code and the explanations.